# (Excel): convert day into minute

Tags: excel, duration

I am working on an Excel sheet where I need to determine my duration in hours, however the start time and end time are given in date. So I need to convert the duration from day to time in hours.

I subtract the start time from end time and I got the duration in day. But I need the duration to be in hours

Comment: Days to hours *24, then hours to minutes *60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just format the result as [h]:mm

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the resulting number by 24, you will get hours.